# WooCommerce multiple variation image

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have some products which have multiple variation and mostly these are sets. Once I create variations on WooCommerce with dropdowns or switches with images, I can only attach an image to first variation like;

1st Selection - Pillow types 
2nd Selection - Bedsheet type

When I click on 1st selection of pillow, image changes to pillow type but in 2nd selection I want to attach images to bedsheet so when someone click on that option it will also show there.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of doing that variation, you can simply create two product 1) Pillow and 2) Bedsheet, where you can add more variation.

Comment: Yeah I have like that but I want also people to purchase a set where they can choose what style they want to purchase for both items under same product.

Comment: For that you can use product bundle plugin like this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-bundle/ .

Comment: Yeah I have used that too but still it does not change main product images on click of options.